# Определить страницу карточки продукта Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Сделать вывод некоторой функции ТОЛЬКО на карточке товара (Bitrix).
Пробовала уже

```
if(CSite::InDir('/catalog/')) {
     var_dump('Here.');    
}
```

Не работает.И еще: .setting.php нет в директории Bitrix, использовав документацию, прописала в php командной строке `Bitrix\Main\Config\Configuration::wnc();.`
Тоже не работает.

Comment: можно смотреть в сторону отложенных функций, если функция просто вывести что то должна до карточки например в хедере. Другой способ, если карточка показывается по каким то правилам в urlrewrite.php например парсится урл и передаётся код товара на страницу, то можно делать проверку есть ли код товара в $_REQUEST. (могут быть ещё варианты)

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно вывести var_dump() только в детальной карточке товара, то почему не вызвать её в result_modifier.php шаблона карточки?